# Get DropDown Values from Database Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP:DropDown list which is populated by the following:

```
public void Fill1()
{
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM2Sage"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products", _con))
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader ddlValues;
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        txtProduct.DataSource = ddlValues;
        txtProduct.DataValueField = "Description";
        txtProduct.DataTextField = "Description";
        txtProduct.DataBind();

        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I need to call the `SalesPrice` from same table and based on the selected value in the drop down update a `ASP:TextBox` Field called `txtUnitAmount`.

I have tried writing it into the same function and it wont let me set the `.Text` value for the `ASP:TextBox`. Can any one suggest a way to achieve this?

Thanks to all for their help so far!

Cheers

Justin

Extra Code for Discussion

```
public void Fill2()
    {
        string getProdValue = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM2Sage"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(getProdValue))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SalesPrice FROM Products WHERE Description = " + Request.Form["txtProduct"].ToString(), _con))
        {
            int getProdCost = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            txtUnitAmount.Text = getProdCost.ToString("###,###0.000");
        }           
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to dispose of the `SQLCommand` if you are using a `using` block. Remember all a `using` block is, is simply a try/catch with a dispose in the `finally` block

Comment: @Nick thanks can you post an example I am just getting to grips with c# and it would really help. Thanks

Comment: I suggest taking a look at LINQ to SQL for your database access. You could write the same logic as above with half the code. Might as well spend your time learning the new way, rather than learning ADO.NET. Regardless, whichever route you do take, I highly suggest getting comfortable with an ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little hard to follow, but I will give it a stab.

You going to have to do another query to the DB based on the onChnge event produced by the drop down change.

You need to wire up the OnChange event for the dropdown and enable autopostback. This can be done through the properties explorer. From the OnChangeEvent, fire your code

Note this code is far from production. You need to do input and return sanitization.

```
var description = Request.Form["txtProduct"].ToString();
using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(getProdValue))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UnitPrice FROM Products WHERE Description = '" + description "'", _con))
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    var unitPrice = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    txtUnitPrice.Text= unitPrice.ToString("###,###0.000");       
}
```

Comment: Ok I thought so if I so that and get the query setup something like this code appended above how do i then set the .text of the ASP:TextBox? as the txt.UnitPrice.DataSource = setVal errors and if I change it to .text it errors

Comment: You dont need to use binding, you could executeScalar on the query to get the value of the unit price and just set the value: txtUnitPrice.Text = unitPrice.ToString("###,###0.000"), where unitPrice is a floating point variable

Comment: @Slappy are you able to post an example of what you mean it's late and I am new to c# and I am a bit confused. thanks so much for helping thus far

Comment: Yep..ExecuteScalar is what you need to get single value: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson03.aspx and then set txtUnitPrice.Text and no datasoure/databinding required.

Comment: I will give it a shot. Dont have an IDE in front of me atm so it might look a little funny

Comment: Posted another bit of code above @Slappy but still not sure how to fire it

Comment: You need to wire up the OnChange event for the dropdown and enable autopostback. This can be done through the properties explorer. From the OnChangeEvent, fire your code.

Comment: @Slappy It didn't work thanks for trying I a have to sleep now I will update the post on my progress tomorrow, again thanks for your help so far!